# Subset of Django Group model in Form

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model for an event which contains the user and a group.

```
curr_User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class CoronaEvent(models.Model):

#query_set = Group.objects.filter(user=curr_User)

user = models.ForeignKey(curr_User, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, related_name='group')
group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
event_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Within my form (I use crispy forms) I want to only offer the list of groups, the current user is member of.

After selecting a group I want to save the result.

What I currently have achieved is to pass the group list from current user (request.user.groups.all() to my form and set the list (by using value_list()) as choices for the choisefield.

But than Django is not able to save the results because the model expects an instance of group instead of the couple.

How can I achieve two use a subset of group in my choices and save the selected group?

Comment: A modelis unaware of the user. So you will need to pass it to the constructor of the form where you work with it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the current User is working. My problem is to manipulate the select option for the group and than save the selected group to the model.